# Another php regex issue

Tags: php, regex

I've a batch of strings:

```
1) tiger lion
2) tiger lions
3) tigers lion
4) tigers lions
5) tiger lion cat
6) dog tiger lion
```

How to use php regex to match only the first four strings?

My regex is bad, please help!

Edit:

```
preg_match("/^(?=.*\btiger|tigers\b)(?=.*\blion|lions\b)/", $mySearchString)
```

Comment: post your terrible regex. ok, post the bad regex.

Comment: is numbers are the part of your input string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, number is not.

Comment: Are these strings individual, separate values, or is each of them is inside a larger `$mySearchString`?

Comment: @stribizhev, they are separated values.

Comment: DO you want to match `lion tiger` ?

Comment: why you want to match the first 4?

Comment: `How to use php regex to match only the first four strings?` that doesn't actually tell us *what* you're trying to match - technically you could just explode that into an array and take the items from indexes 0 - 3 - are you specifically trying to match `tiger. lion.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `^(?=.*\btiger|tigers\b)(?=.*\blion|lions\b)` checks for the beginning of the string (`^`), then checks if `tiger` or `tigers` as *almost* whole words is somewhere inside the string, then if `lion` or `lions` is somewhere inside the string, **but it does not match any characters** since there is no subpattern that would consume characters.

You can use the following regex:

```
^tigers?\s+lions?$
```

The `^` and `$` anchors will make sure your input string only contains `tigers` and `lions`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC4xC3/1)

Or, if the these 2 words can be swapped:

```
^(?:tigers?\s+lions?|lions?\s+tigers?)$
```

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/GTFwQu):

```
$re = "#^tigers?\s+lions?$#m"; 
$str = "tiger lion\ntiger lions\ntigers lion\ntigers lions\ntiger lion cat\ndog tiger lion"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => tiger lion
            [1] => tiger lions
            [2] => tigers lion
            [3] => tigers lions
        )
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the ambiguous question.. This is the perfect solution to my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. In case you need to check for these 2 words inside larger strings, you can use your look-aheads, but be sure to match or capture at least something unless you are splitting. :)